# How to create this custom list view

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-lists

I am looking to create a list view which contains a image and 2 textviews and one Button.like in this format

```
      Textview1   
image Textview2                               Button
```

in the above format i have created another layout .now i want to inflate this layout onto listview.for images say i have 6 images in the drawable  folder named as image_1,image_2,image_3,image_4,image_5,image-6.
i am not able to understand from the examples that i have found in google.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/stub"
    android:layout_height="50sp" android:layout_width="100sp" android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ImageView>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="ADD" android:id="@+id/badd"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="15dp"></Button>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tvname" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tvprice" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
```

Please provide me some android code to achive this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do can be achieved using CustomAdapter. Its is the most common thing which is used in android application.

Below links can be useful for you.

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx

Comment: well thank you for this links sir.can you past some code it will be help full for me.and on list item click i want to show the selected image in the other activity can you tell me how can i achive this.

Answer (score 0):

To get ListView with images(thumbnail) along with description, following tutorial can be helpful to you. And what exactly you are looking for,

[Android Custom ListView Example with Images](http://www.android-development-tutorial.net/android-custom-listview-example-with-images/)

Comment: Can you add some content from the link?